# Can not add Datatable Elements in a new Datatable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to Add elements in a Datatable using this method.
I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: There is no row at position 0.

```
public DataTable slope(DataTable createPath)
{
    DataTable slopes = new DataTable(); 
    slopes.Columns.Add("Slope Line 1", typeof(double));
    slopes.Columns.Add("Slope Line 2", typeof(double));
    slopes.Columns.Add("Direction 1", typeof(string));
    slopes.Columns.Add("Direction 2", typeof(string));
    for (int i = 2; i < createPath.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        slopes.Rows[i - 2][0] = Math.Atan2((Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i - 1][2]) - Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i - 2][2])),
            (Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i - 1][1]) - Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i - 2][1])));            

        slopes.Rows[i - 2][1] = Math.Atan2((Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i][2]) - Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i - 1][2])),
            (Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i][1]) - Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i - 1][1])));
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < slopes.Rows.Count; j++ )
    {
        for (int k=0; k<2; k++)
        {
            if ( Convert.ToDouble(slopes.Rows[j][k])== 0)
                slopes.Rows[j][k + 2] = "Straight Right";
            else if (Convert.ToDouble(slopes.Rows[j][k]) == Math.PI)
                slopes.Rows[j][k + 2] = "Straight Left";
            else if (Convert.ToDouble(slopes.Rows[j][k]) == (Math.PI / 2))
                slopes.Rows[j][k + 2] = "Straight Up";
            else if (Convert.ToDouble(slopes.Rows[j][k]) == -(Math.PI / 2))
                slopes.Rows[j][k + 2] = "Straight Down";
            else 
                slopes.Rows[j][k + 2] = "Slant";
        }
    }
    return slopes;
}
```

Comment: `slopes` table is empty. you didn't add rows to it

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, in the for Loop

Answer (score 1):

you should add rows to `slopes` table before you try to access them like this `slopes.Rows[i - 2]`

```
for (int i = 2; i < createPath.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var row = slopes.NewRow();
    row[0] = Math.Atan2((Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i - 1][2]) - Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i - 2][2])),
        (Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i - 1][1]) - Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i - 2][1])));


    row[1] = Math.Atan2((Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i][2]) - Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i - 1][2])),
        (Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i][1]) - Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i - 1][1])));
    slopes.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
slopes.Rows.Add(What you are adding);
```